# Plotting AnalogWaveform<TData> on the Waveformgraph with PlotWaveforms method using Measurement Studio 2013 in .Net

Tags: .net, plot, waveform, measurement-studio

I am using Measurement Studio 2013 with VS 2012.

I am fetching data from NI PXI 5122 which I want to plot on the graph. I can clearly see the records when printed in console or even on the gridview but I am unable to plot it on the WaveformGraph. Here is my code:

```
    static void PlotWaveformsOnGraph(AnalogWaveformCollection<double> waveforms)
     {       
           List<AnalogWaveform<double>> waveformList = new List <AnalogWaveform<double>>(waveforms);
           MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
           main.waveformGraph.PlotWaveforms(waveformList.ToArray());
     }
```

there is no error in the above code, also the data is present in WaveformList but not plotting on the graph.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @HåkenLid - The problem here is I am not able to see the values plotted on the WaveformGraph. The graph is clear wit no plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating a `MainWindow` instance dynamically in your `PlotWaveformsOnGraph` method because you cannot reach the waveformGraph object from context of the method? If so, you might consider the following:

1. Passing the waveformGraph object to which you plot your waveforms as a parameter to your `PlotWaveformsOnGraph` method. This way, you can access the `PlotWaveformsAppend` method on the waveformGraph from within your static method.

This might look like:

```
static void PlotWaveformsOnGraph(AnalogWaveformCollection<double> waveforms,
   WaveformGraph graph)
{
    var waveformList = new List<AnalogWaveform<double>>(waveforms);
    graph.PlotWaveforms(waveformList.ToArray());
}
```

2. Remove the static keyword from the `PlotWaveformsOnGraph` method. Assuming `PlotWaveformsOnGraph` is a member of your `MainWindow` class, and your window has a `WaveformGraph` control on it, you can access the waveformGraph from within your method. Do you have a specific reason for making this method static?

It looks like more progress on this issue is being made [here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Measurement-Studio-for-NET/Plotting-AnalogWaveformCollection-lt-double-gt-data-onto-the/td-p/3162860/highlight/false).